# Apply Sprite Image data to Button Icon

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am stuck with a Flex 3 legacy application and I need to be able to dynamically apply  generated Sprites containing different gradient fills as well as Embedded SVG images to the icon of a button. Can anybody help with how I cast the Sprite to the button icon? Do i have to copy the image data out of the DisplayObject and cast is as a Class somehow?

thanx,